# Render different menus using ASP.NET MVC ActionFilters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, action-filter

I have a standard menu using ul and li tags. And in my database, I have a table Users with a field 'certificate' and depending the value of this 'certificate', the user will see or not some items of the menu.

I was reading some texts and I think I will have to use `ActionFilters`. Is this right?

So, how can I render different menus depending which user is accessing?

thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the Html.RenderAction methods that the [futures](http://www.asp.net/mvc/download/) assembly introduces.  They can let you, in a very clean fashion, render an action method.  This means that you can have a MenuController (for example) that takes care of all of the logic about what menu items you can render.  Then it can just pass a simple data structure to the view, whose responsibility it is to render that data structure.  Very clean.

Comment: I've downloaded the futures assembly but I can't make it work. It's only showing RenderPartial... nothing about RenderAction

Comment: You need to add <add namespace="Microsoft.Web.Mvc"/> to the pages / namespaces node in web.config.  That will bring in the additional features and extension methods from futures

Comment: Also what if we need for the same user manage CRUD  in the page... Which approach is better to implement?

Answer (score 2):

I would consider using RenderPartial or RenderAction instead. ActionFilters are not quite suited to that kind of thing. Take a look at [this article](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2009/06/18/the-filter-viewdata-anti-pattern.aspx).